# Apache 2 Failed to bind to port, port is open

Tags: apache, port

Alright so I installed an apache server and verified it in the firewall. It has access to ports 80 and 443. I am running Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop Edition

I ran *"sudo ufw app info "Apache Full"*" to verify the firewall rules.

> Profile: Apache Full
> Title: Web Server (HTTP,HTTPS)
> Description: Apache v2 is the next generation of the omnipresent Apache web server.
>
> Ports: 80,443/tcp

I also tried checking if any ports are open under port 80, which there is a service for apache2. I ran "*sudo netstat -ltnp | grep ':80'*"

> tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8002          :::*                    LISTEN      32641/java
>
> tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN       28722/apache2
>
> tcp6       0      0 :::8000                 :::*                    LISTEN      10738/java
>
> tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8001          :::*                    LISTEN      1649/java

Then I tried closing the service and checked if the port is open again, by doing "*sudo service apache2 stop*" then "*sudo netstat -ltnp | grep ':80'*"

> tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8002          :::*                    LISTEN      32641/java
>
> tcp6       0      0 :::8000                 :::*                    LISTEN      10738/java
>
> tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8001          :::*                    LISTEN      1649/java

I've even went into the physical router and opened the port, the same setup works on other services just for apache.

Edit: I forgot to say, my URL isn't working. It just says

> This site can’t be reached 24.221.202.149 took too long to respond.

My website is http://24.221.202.149/

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: Sorry forgot to say that the website won't load. I edited it to have more info.

Answer (score 0):

I use sprint (with a static IP) as a provider. They block common web service host IP's including port 80.